# Quick and reliable algorithm to determine the existence of a QR code in an image?

Tags: algorithm, computer-vision

Without implementing openCV or calling QR code's recognition API, is there any quick and reliable algorithm to determine the existence of a QR code in an image?

The intention of this question is to improve the user experience of scanning QR code. When QR code's recognition fails, the program needs to know whether there really exists a QR code for it to scan and recognize QR code again or there is not any QR code so that the program can call other procedures.

To echo some response, the detection program doesn't need to be 100% accurate but returns an accurate result with reasonable probability. If we can use openCV here, Fourier Transformation will be easily implemented to detect whether there is an obvious high frequency in an image, which is a good sign of the existence of QR. But the integration of openCV will largely increase the size of my program, which I want to avoid.

Comment: If there existed a detection algorithm that was both quick and reliable, then any decent recognition API would already be using it. So if your existing QR code recognition process fails, you won't gain anything by trying to find a QR code yourself.

Comment: I can't fully agree. If this argument works, there won't be any improvement for all the existing algorithms or programs.

Comment: The detection program doesn't need to be 100% accurate but returns an accurate result with reasonable probability. If we can use openCV here, Fourier Transformation will be easily implemented to detect whether there is an obvious high frequency in an image, which is a good sign of the existence of QR. But the integration of openCV will largely increase the size of my program, which I want to avoid. @Kevin

Comment: Do you need to distinguish between a QR code and other 2D codes, such as Data Matrix?

Comment: @Rethunk Thanks! It is not a must. I don't want to make the question over-sophisticated. It intends to make some minor improvement on current QR code recognition algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) convert the image into grayscale
2) divide the image into cells of n x m, say 3 x 3. This procedure intends to guarantee that at the least one cell will be fully covered by possible QR code if any
3) implement 2D Fourier Transformation for all the cells. If in any cell there is an significantly large value in high-frequency area in both X and Y axis, there is a high likelihood that there exists a QR code

I am addressing a probability issue rather than 100% accurate detection. In this algorithm, chessboard will be detected as QR code as well.

Answer (score 2):

It's great that you want to provide feedback to a user. Providing graphics that indicate the user is "getting warmer" in finding the QR code can make the process of finding and reading a code quicker and smoother.

It looks like you already have your answer, but to provide a more robust solution and/or have options, you might try one or more of the following:

- Use N iterations to morph dark pixels closed, and the resulting squarish checkboard pattern should more closely resemble a filled square. This was part of a detection method I used to determine if a DataMatrix (a similar 2D code) was present whether it was readable or not. Whether this works will depend greatly on your background.
- Before applying FFT, considering finding the affine transform to reduce perspective distortion. Analyzing FFT data can be a pain if the frequencies have a bit of spread because of foreshortening.
- You could get some decent results using texture measures such as Local Binary Patterns (LBPs) or older techniques such as Law's Texture methods. You might even get lucky and be able to detect slight differences in the histogram of texture measures between a 2D code and a checkerboard pattern.
- In regions of checkerboard-like patterns, look for the 3 guide features at the corners of the QR code. You could try SIFT/SURF-like methods, or perhaps implement a simpler match method by using a limited number of correlation templates that are tested in scale space.
- Speaking of scale space: generate an image pyramid to save yourself the trouble of searching for squares in full-resolution images. You could try edge-preserving or non-edge-preserving methods to generate the smaller images in the pyramid, or perhaps a combination of both.
- If you have code for fast kernel processing, you might try a corner detection method to reduce the amount of data you process to detect checkerboard-like patterns.
- Look for clear bimodal distributions of grayscale values in squarish regions. 2D codes on paper labels tend to have stark contrast even though 2D codes on paper are quite readable at low contrast.
- Rather than look for bimodal distribution of grayscale values, you could look for regions where gradient magnitudes are very consistent, nearly unimodal.
- If you know the min/max area limits of a readable QR code, you could probabilistically sample the image for patches that match one or more of the above criteria: one mode of gradient magnitudes, nearly evenly space corner points, etc. If a patch does look promising, then jump to another random position with the caveat that the new patch was not previously found unpromising.

If you have the memory for an image pyramid, then working with reduced resolution images could be advantageous since you could try a number of tests fairly quickly.

As far as user interaction is concerned, you might also update the "this might be a QR code" graphic multiple times during pre-processing, and indicate degrees of confidence with progressively stronger/greener graphics (or whatever color is appropriate for the local culture). For example, if a patch of texture has a roughly 60% chance of being a QR code, you might display a thin yellowish-green rectangle with a dashed border. For an 80% - 90% likelihood you might display a solid rectangle of a more saturated green color. If you can update the graphics about every 100 - 200 milliseconds then a user will have some idea that some action such as moving the smart phone is helping or hurting.